# React Axios: Sometimes State Doesn't Pass onClick event

Tags: reactjs, axios, state

I'm working on some code. Basically When button 1 (id=1) is clicked, it display its value (where id===1). When button 2 is clicked, it display the value of button "2", etc The code are working fine.

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            collections: [],
            collection: [],
            initialVal: [],
    };

    choseSeason = event => {
        // console.log(event.target.id);
        this.setState({
            initialVal: event.target.id,
        }, () => console.log('initialVal: '+this.state.initialVal));
    }

    componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://myapi`)
      .then(res => {
        const collections = res.data;
        this.setState({
            collections,
        collection: collections.map(collection=>(collection)),
        //this is console log line 29
        initialVal: collections[0].id,
         });
      })
  }
render() {
    const { collections = [] } = this.state;
    const collection = this.state;
    const nowId = collections.filter(collection => collection.id === this.state.initialVal);   
    console.log(nowId); //this is console log line 56
    return (
        <Container className="collection">

                <div className="">
                    {collections.length ? collections.map(c=>(
                            <div className="nav"><NavLink activeClassName={"active3"} onClick={this.choseSeason}><span id={c.id}>{'SS'+c.name.slice(7, 9)}</span></NavLink></div>
                        ))
                    :
                    <React.Fragment/>
                    }
                </div>

           {nowId.length ? 

            <div className="wrapper">

                <div className="item1 flex">

                <div className="flex right">
                    <div className="title vBot">
                        {nowId[0].collection_titles[0].title}
                    </div>
                </div>
...
```

Flow:

1. ComponentDidMount get value from first data from my api, and put it in state (InitialVal)
2. in Render, nowId filtered the id where id === this.state.initialVal and display it
3. in Render, on NavLink Click, it changes the value of initialVal (choseSeason function)

Everything works fine, but sometimes when clicking (can be after 2nd click, or 100th click) the button passes '' to initialValue which made my component render nothing. (in below picture, on the 10th click, it passes nothing)

[image: picture form console.log()]

Does this have anything to do with my logic / syntax? please help! thank you!

Comment: Could you share a working code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass id in choseSeason method and update the state

```
        constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          collections: [],
          collection: [],
          initialVal: [],
    };

    choseSeason = id => {
      // console.log(id);
      this.setState({
          initialVal: id,
      }, () => console.log('initialVal: '+this.state.initialVal));
    }

    componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://myapi`)
    .then(res => {
      const collections = res.data;
      this.setState({
          collections,
      collection: collections.map(collection=>(collection)),
      //this is console log line 29
      initialVal: collections[0].id,
      });
    })
    }
    render() {
    const { collections = [] } = this.state;
    const collection = this.state;
    const nowId = collections.filter(collection => collection.id === 
    this.state.initialVal);   
    console.log(nowId); //this is console log line 56
    return (
      <Container className="collection">

              <div className="">
                  {collections.length ? collections.map(c=>(
                          <div className="nav"><NavLink activeClassName={"active3"} onClick={()=>this.choseSeason(c.id)}><span id={c.id}>{'SS'+c.name.slice(7, 9)}</span></NavLink></div>
                      ))
                  :
                  <React.Fragment/>
                  }
              </div>

        {nowId.length ? 

          <div className="wrapper">

              <div className="item1 flex">

              <div className="flex right">
                  <div className="title vBot">
                      {nowId[0].collection_titles[0].title}
                  </div>
              </div>
    ...
```